# Scala referencing function in another function

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-breeze

I am relatively new to Scala, been using R and MATLAB before. I have written the following piece of code in Scala. I've written the same code in R and MATLAB, and in both it works just fine, but due to my inexperience with Scala the code below does not work.

```
import breeze.linalg._
import breeze.numerics.exp
import scala.math.log



val data =  breeze.stats.distributions.Uniform(0, 1)

val ep: DenseMatrix[Double] = DenseMatrix.rand(39, 3, data).t

val a = DenseVector(1.0)

val out: DenseMatrix[Double] = tile(a, 1, 39)

val fout: DenseVector[Double] = out.toDenseVector

val A: Double = 0.0

val B: Double = 1.0

val eta: Double = 2.0 / Math.pow(B - A, 2.0)

val nCol: Int = 39

val nRow: Int = 3

var gA = 0.0

var gB = 0.0

var gamma = 0.0


def SubstFunction(predictions: DenseVector[Double], expertsPrediction: DenseVector[Double]): Double = {

  gA = -(1 / eta) * log(predictions dot exp(-eta * (expertsPrediction :- A)) :^ 2.0)

  gB = -(1 / eta) * log(predictions dot exp(-eta * (expertsPrediction :- B)) :^ 2.0)

  gamma = (0.5 * (B + A)) - ((gB - gA) / 2 * (B - A))

  gamma

}


def prediction(Input: DenseMatrix[Double], outcomes: DenseVector[Double]): DenseVector[Double] = {

  var weights = DenseVector(1.0,1.0,1.0)

  val AAprediction = DenseVector.fill(nCol)(0.0)

  //DenseVector.ones[Double](nCol).t

  for (l<-0 to Input.cols) {

    val normalisedWeights = weights / sum(weights)

    AAprediction(l) = SubstFunction(normalisedWeights, Input(::,l))

    weights = normalisedWeights :* exp(eta :* (Input(::,l) :- outcomes(l)) :^ 2.0).toDenseVector
  }
  AAprediction: DenseVector[Double]
}

prediction(ep,fout)
```

I think problem might be when prediction calls `sbstFunction` in it. I am using Scala Work sheet in intelliJ. When I run the code I get no error but I don't get a numeric output instead I get:

> ```
> <function1> res1: Unit = ()
> ```

Update: I have fixed the code and now I am getting the following error:

> Column must be in bounds for slice!

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
def prediction(Input: DenseMatrix[Double], outcomes: DenseMatrix[Double]) = 
  (AAprediction: DenseVector[Double]) => {
```

This is declaration of `prediction`. It's a method that takes two arguments and returns a function. Quickly looking at the code it looks like it's the function has type `DenseVector[Double] => DenseVector[Double]`, a more precise declaration would be:

```
def prediction(Input: DenseMatrix[Double], 
   outcomes: DenseMatrix[Double]): DenseVector[Double] => DenseVector[Double]
```

Essentially what it doing in `prediction(ep,out)` is constructing a function. A much simpler example:

```
scala> def addConst(x:Int):Int => Int = y => x + y 
addConst: (x: Int)Int => Int

scala> addConst(10)
res1: Int => Int = <function1>
```

In this case, again, we built a function. To use this function we could either call `res1(5)` or

```
scala> addConst(10)(5)
res2: Int = 15
```

Comment: I think the problem is that AAprediction does not get filled inside the loop, or there is no output.

Answer (score 0):

The basic function in scala is defined like this:

```
def f(x:Int):Int = {
  x
}
```

Where you define the input type `Int`, return type `Int` and the function body.

What you have is (for the `prediction` method):

```
def f(x:Int) = (y:Int) => y + x
```

where `f` returns another function `Int => Int`. In your case the `prediction` function returns a function `DenseVector[Double] => DenseVector[Double]` that's why nothing gets executed.

Comment: By doing so I get few issues with my code, perhaps that means my code is not correct as well. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify part, which you did wrong or misunderstood, but I believe it will be enough to understand what went wrong and you will know how to fix it.

You defined prediction function which looks like this:

`def prediction(addTo: Int, multiplyBy: Int) = (number: Int) => {
  (number + addTo) * multiplyBy
}`

and then you used 2 required parameters, and now if, you would substitute this variables, it would look like this:
`prediction(2, 3)`

`number => (number + 2) * 3` <- and this is a function, isn't it?

To calculate the final value, you need to use 3rd argument which is inside an [anonymous function](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html).

So in our example `prediction(2, 3)(1)` would give us an actual output 9.
Or you can define `def addTwoMultiplyByThree = prediction(2, 3)`
and use it with multiple other values.

Comment: This is an expression `(number + 2) * 3`

Comment: `number => (number + 2) * 3` this is a function.